# T-SQL Get Rows With Similar Company Name Using Levenshtein

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this [Levenshtein function](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2010/12/sql_server-fuzzy-strings-matching-using-levenshtein-algorithm-t-sql-vs-clr/) for T-SQL which works well (I'm not worried about performance). Now I want to write a query that returns all rows where the Levenshtein distance is less than x (where x might be 5 for example) using the Company name field to do the comparison.

I've tried the following, but it returns thousands of duplicate rows.

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts c1, Contacts c2
WHERE dbo.ufnCompareString(c1.Company, c2.Company) < 5
AND c1.id <> c2.id
```

I would like it to show a list like this:

```
1   Apple Experts
20  Apple Experts Inc.
240 H&K Paving
21  H and K Paving
98  HK Paving
189 H.K. Paving
5   J.M. Lawn Care
105 JM Lawn Care
```

Is it possible to do something like this? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I ended up with a query that looks something like this. I found that there were some "invalid" entries causing the problems I was having:

```
SELECT c1.ContactId, c1.Company, c1.LastName, c1.FirstName,
   c2.ContactId, c2.Company, c2.LastName, c2.FirstName
FROM Contacts c1, Contacts c2
WHERE Cast(c1.ContactId AS INT) < Cast(c2.ContactId AS INT)
   AND c1.Company IS NOT NULL 
   AND Replace(c1.Company, ' ', '') <> ''
   AND c2.Company IS NOT NULL
   AND Replace(c2.Company, ' ', '') <> ''
   AND Len(c1.Company) > 6
   AND Len(c2.Company) > 6
   AND dbo.ufnCompareString(c1.Company, c2.Company) < 5
```

Note that the query is pretty slow running (on about 12,000 records) and I also have a different query that is more effective. The goal was to find duplicate companies that had been entered using slightly different company names and this query returned too many false positives. As to the query I actually used, it's too complicated to show here and outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the duplicates, use this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts c1, Contacts c2
WHERE dbo.ufnCompareString(c1.Company, c2.Company) < 5
AND c1.id < c2.id
```

It returns all unique pairs of contacts, whose distance is less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have there should work properly, if you are getting duplicates look at the content of the Contacts table.